# Django URL resolving infrastructure stops working

Tags: python, django, fastcgi, django-urls

We recently launched a new Django-powered website, and we are experiencing the oddest bug:

The site is running under Apache with mod_fastcgi. Everything works fine for a while, and then the URL tag and reverse() functionality stops working. Instead of returning the expected URL, they return "".

We haven't noticed anything in Apache's log file; there are no errors being generated by Django. And (the kicker) the problem only occurs in production mode; we can't reproduce it when DEBUG=True.

Any thoughts on where we should be looking for the problem?

**Update**: It turned out to be a problem with settings.LANGUAGES, although we haven't determined exactly *why* that broke things.

Comment: when the problem occurs are the responses from the server very slow?

Comment: @rz: not from what we can tell. We're also running memcache to keep things sain.

Comment: Have you tried running behind mod_wsgi to see if the problem goes away?  I've had really strange issues with fastcgi in the past.

Comment: @rz: yeah, that's what we ended up doing. So far, the issues we've seen have gone away. :-)

Comment: As i turns out, that _didn't_ solve the problem...

Comment: What Django/python versions are you running?

Comment: @Matthew: Django 1.1 and Python 2.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has happened to me before. Normally it's due to a 'broken' urls.py file. There are two things that make this kind of bug really hard to fix:

- It could be the urls.py file in *any* of the apps that breaks the reverse() function, so knowing that reverse() breaks for app X doesn't mean the error is in that particular application's urls.py.
- Django won't even notify you of errors in the urls.py file, unless you somehow manage to crash the site by doing something really, really nasty in the urls.py file.

**Debugging:** The way I go around fixing this is by manually disabling all applications (just comment out their line in INSTALLED_APPS) and checking reverse() works. If it still works, then I enable the next app, until it breaks. I know, very rudimentary stuff, but it works :)

Answer (score 2):

Django has a odd behaviour when matching urls in a environment that isn't under debug mode.

For example, with DEBUG=False, Django will ignore urls such as:

> > > url(r'^', include('someapp.urls')),

specifically in the case above, you could let the string empty:

> > > url(r'', include('someapp.urls')),

In other words, check your regexes.

Can you put your urls.py here to be analyzed?